# How to code a play and pause button in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have made a simple game in flash. It includes a timer, falling objects and an object controlled by using swipe. So is there a way to stop every activity with the pause button and start it back again with the play button. Basically I want the whole stage to pause and play using buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it automaticaly. You could base your entire game on a timer (even for animations and physics) and pause this timer. But this is a feature you have to think about during the very design of your game. Now I guess you just have to pause every movieclip, cancel your listeners to `ENTER_FRAME` and pause your timer.

Many game engines such as [Flixel](http://www.flixel.org/) or [FlashPunk](http://useflashpunk.net/) include this feature

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this in as3 is to run two timers, one that always runs at about 500ms and another that runs at framerate that varies with the speed of the game.  Something like

```
public var speedControl:int = 15;
public var tick:Timer;

public function timers():void{
    tick = new Timer(1000/speedControl);
    tick.addEventListener(TimerEvent:TIMER,tickd);
    tick.start();
}

public function tickd(t:TimerEvent):void{
    // the timer has ticked
}

public function pause():void{
    tick.stop();
}

public function play():void{
    tick.start();
}
```

This is a basic example of course created on the fly, but you can call the pause or play button with a standard event listener.  If your whole stage runs off of the timer, it will all stop.  I use a second timer however that doesnt get stopped and started with the functions also.  You really do want some things to run all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't mind using the FP 11.8 Beta, it has that feature nativly to stop all movieclips recursively. Check it out here:

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashruntimes/flashplayer/